# Use tar and gz to create archive in Ubuntu Terminal

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, tar, gz

I want to archive 3 folders, given their names in Ubuntu command prompt.
When I use `tar -c abc tt zz` -> it will do nothing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You either need to redirect that output to your tarball name as in:

```
tar -c abc tt zz > tarball.tar
```

(Careful, that will overwrite tarball.tar if it's already there) or you need to use the `-f` flag for tar and specify a filename as in:

```
tar -cf tarball.tar abc tt zz
```

Comment: how about the use of gz?

Comment: if you add the `-z` flag to the tar command it will tell it to use gzip compression (e.g. `tar -czf tarball.tar.gz abc tt zz`), `-j` will use bzip2 (e.g. `tar -cjf tarball.tar.bz2 abc tt zz`).  The way that tar handles it's output is the same whether or not compression is used.  Without the `-f` it goes to `stdout`.

Answer (score 10):

You can use [this](http://discussion.accuwebhosting.com/linux-server-commands/681-tar-command-how-tar-un-tar-zip-unzip-folder-linux-command.html) command

```
 tar -cvzf tarname.tar.gz a b c
```

eg:

```
x@x:/tmp/aas$ touch a b c
x@x:/tmp/aas$ ls
a  b  c
x@x:/tmp/aas$ tar cvzf tarname.tar.gz a b c
a
b
c
x@x:/tmp/aas$ ls
a  b  c  tarname.tar.gz
x@x:/tmp/aas$ rm a b c
x@x:/tmp/aas$ ls
tarname.tar.gz
x@x:/tmp/aas$ gunzip -c tarname.tar.gz | tar xvf -
a
b
c
x@x:/tmp/aas$ ls
a  b  c  tarname.tar.gz
x@x:/tmp/aas$
```

Comment: how about the use of gz?

Comment: this will tar and gzip it in a single command. If you wish you can do it seperately as well

Comment: The link is broken